# How to remove Excel file headers C#, Oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

```
Sting TempFileLocation="Filelocation";
 Sting tempfilename ="FileName";
 Sting TabName ="TabName$";
 string xConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source="  +TempFileLocation+     tempfilename +".xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
 var conn = new OleDbConnection(xConnStr);
 string ColumnName ="[columename] varchar(255)"
 conn.Open();
 var cmd = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [" + TabName + "] (" + ColumnName + ")", conn);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conn.Close();
```

Any one know hoe to delete Excel file column headers.
To soluation for this 
Visit  [Cant create Excel file using OLEDB C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807569/cant-create-excel-file-using-oledb-c-sharp/9807676#9807676)

I used temporary headers. after create the Excel i need to delete all temporary headers. Please anyone know how to do it please let me know . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you don't want the temporary column names you created in excel, you can simply set `HDR=NO` in your connection string. This property is whether or not you want the first row in the excel worksheet as your column titles; if set to no then your columns will all be named F1, F2, F3 etc. instead.