# Cannot create excel file using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I found in several sources how to ctreate excel file, for example

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37055/Working-with-MS-Excel-xls-xlsx-Using-MDAC-and-Oled#create
- [Cant create Excel file using OLEDB C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807569/cant-create-excel-file-using-oledb-c-sharp)
- http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/608150-generate-excel-file-without-excel

but when I tried to use suggested code I have got an error on command Open() of OleDbConnection.

---

> *System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'D:\Import2013\Imported\254\template.xls'.
>   Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path
>   name correctly.*

---

That is a code I used.

```
string subFolder = Session["LoginID"] != null ? Server.MapPath( "Imported" ) + "\\" + Convert.ToString( Session["LoginID"] ) : "";
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( subFolder ))
{
    Response.Redirect( "Default.aspx" );
    Response.End();
}
StringBuilder commandText = new StringBuilder( "CREATE TABLE [Imported] (" );
if (!Directory.Exists( subFolder ))
    Directory.CreateDirectory( subFolder );
string fileName = subFolder + "\\template.xls";
if (File.Exists( fileName ))
    File.Delete( fileName );
var connectionString = string.Format( "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Mode=Write;IMEX=1\"", fileName );
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection( connectionString ))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lvFieldNames.Count; i++)
    {
        commandText.Append( "[" + lvFieldNames[i].FieldName + "] varchar(64)" );
        if (i < lvFieldNames.Count - 1)
            commandText.Append( ", " );
    }
    commandText.Append( ");" );
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand( commandText.ToString(), connection ))
    {
        if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Open(); //I have got an error on this line
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Please, explain what I did wrong.

Comment: This is a pot shot.... If you installed the x64 version of this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255  try installing the 32bit version

Comment: @Mick Jet.OleDb.4.0 exist only in a 32 bit version and the error would be different if the program was compiled for 64bit.

Comment: Are you able to just OPEN an existing file xls in that folder?

Comment: @Steve, yes, I haven't a problem with opening and reading excel files in this folder.

Comment: Additionally, I tried to use code File.Create(fileName); to check if I have permissions to creating files in that folder, and file was created.

Comment: Remove IMEX=1 in the extended properties.

Comment: There's this...  https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/source/checkout

You can either use that or take a look at their source code.  What I think is going on is that your code opens an existing xls file, you want to actually create the file which is probably a seperate process.  You need additional code before you attempt the connection.Open()

Comment: @Stave, ok, excel file is now created, thanks. But now is another problem, seems cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); not working, as excel file is empty, I tried to use cmd string from debugging on SQL Server and table was created without error.. Can you please help me, what do I need do that in first line was names of fields?

Comment: @Mick, thanks for your link, but yet I want to use standard microsoft libraries.

Comment: The code for writing down the headers is correct, but I cannot see the column names used. The limitation if I remember well is a maximum 64 chars IN THE COLUMN NAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IMEX=1 in the connection string puts the Excel File in read only mode.

[See ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/standard-alternative/)

> "IMEX=1;" tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers,
>   dates, strings etc) data columns as text. **Note that this option might
>   affect excel sheet write access negative**.

To create the Excel file you need IMEX=0 or IMEX=2

Comment: I left in Extended Properties only "Excel 8.0" and it's working now as I need. For reading I used only "Excel 8.0" too, but after reading articles above, I'm lost my right way. Thanks all very much for your help.

Comment: I suggest you to try [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/). You could write snippets of code in that editor and try them right away. This tool helps a lot with these confusing situations.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. I'll look at it in my free time.